# Undefined local variable or method `_setup_mocks' in cucumber 0.8.5 and rspec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, rspec2

Inside of : `features/support/env.rb`

```
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'
```

I just ported my project to a new cpu and it's returning this error on everything:

```
undefined local variable or method `_setup_mocks'
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Gems :

```
rspec (2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.18)
rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.18)
ccumber 0.8.5
rails (3.0.0.rc2, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.2.6)

ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

It also looks like all those versions of rails are phantom rails versions. If I try to remove them I get :

```
>> sudo gem uninstall -v=2.2.2 rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rails`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber 0.8.5 is not compatible with :

```
rspec 2.0.0.beta.18
rspec 2.0.0.beta.17
rspec 2.0.0.beta.8
rspec 2.0.0.beta.7
```

But worked with :

```
rspec 2.0.0.beta.10
```